# Nuxt How to send async props

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, nuxt.js

I've been having trouble with Nuxt2.15 (Vue.js).
I want to send the data from parent component to child component that parent components fetched. And, I want to fetch another data from a child component by useing the data from the parent component.　But props data is undefined in the child component. I tried to use "watch" and "computed" in the child component. But I couldn't make it work.  I would appreciate it if someone can show me how to fix it.

Parent

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Child v-bind:exampleData="exampleData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Child from "./Child.vue";
export default {
  name: "Parent",
  components: {
    Child,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      exampleData: [],
    };
  },

  async created() {
    const exampleData = await fetchData();
    this.exampleData = exampleData
  },

};
</script>
```

Child

```
<template>
  <div><!-- show result data here  --></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: ["exampleData"],

  async created() {
    let abc = this.exampleData;
    // abc is undefined
    const resultData = await fetData(abc);
    this.result = resultData;
  },

  data() {
    return {
      result: [],
    };
  },

};
```

Comment: *" I tried to use `watch` and `computed` in the child component."* - `computed` cannot be async. `watch` is correct solution. Show your attempt instead what clearly does not work...

Comment: Thank you Michal. Actually watch worked right after I posted this.

Comment: is there any reason you are not using `asyncData` or `Fetch` functions instead of `created` ?

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comment. Actually, We use mixin to get data from a server in the project that I'm working on.  so I just simplified that part to explain my situation. If it was my personal project that I made from scratch, and If I was familiar with Vue and Nuxt(in fact, I mainly use React), I would probably use store and asyncData or Fetch since I don't like using props.  Maybe in that case Fetch is better? And In this project useing asyncData is better instead of created? I'm totally new to vue and nuxt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `mounted()` method instead of `created()` like this:

```
<template>
  <div><!-- show result data here  --></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: ["exampleData"],
  async mounted() {
    let abc = this.exampleData;
    // abc is undefined
    const resultData = await fetData(abc);
    this.result = resultData;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      result: [],
    };
  },
};
```

But, if the data passed from the parent is asynchronous or could be changed at some moment, I would recommend using the watch prop like this:

```
<template>
  <div><!-- show result data here  --></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: ["exampleData"],
  data() {
    return {
      result: [],
    };
  },
  watch: {
   exampleData() {
     const resultData = await fetData(this.exampleData);
     this.result = resultData;
   }
  }
};
```